# MySQL - SELECT unknown colum in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql

I was using the following query:

```
$sql = $db->Query("SELECT a.id, a.t_name, a.cpc FROM twitter a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.user LEFT JOIN followed c ON c.user_id = '".$data['id']."' AND c.site_id = a.id WHERE a.active = '0' AND (b.coins >= a.cpc AND a.cpc >= '2') AND (c.site_id IS NULL AND a.user !='".$data['id']."')".$dbt_value." ORDER BY a.cpc DESC".($site['mysql_random'] == 1 ? ', RAND()' : '')." LIMIT 14");
```

But I would like to add in:

```
AND (a.d_max > '0' OR a.d_max = u) AND (a.max > '0' OR a.max = u)
```

So I added that in to:

```
$sql = $db->Query("SELECT a.id, a.t_name, a.cpc FROM twitter a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.id = a.user LEFT JOIN followed c ON c.user_id = '".$data['id']."' AND c.site_id = a.id WHERE a.active = '0' AND (a.d_max > '0' OR a.d_max = u) AND (a.max > '0' OR a.max = u) AND (b.coins >= a.cpc AND a.cpc >= '2') AND (c.site_id IS NULL AND a.user !='".$data['id']."')".$dbt_value." ORDER BY a.cpc DESC".($site['mysql_random'] == 1 ? ', RAND()' : '')." LIMIT 14");
```

However I receive the following error:

SQL Error: Unknown column 'u' in 'where clause':

I know this should be so simple but I'm just missing it, would you guys be able to spot what's wrong?

Comment: There is no field `u`, do you mean a literal  `'u'` (note the quotes)?

Comment: I have to columns d_max and max which can have any numeric number or the letter u.  I would like to select out rows which have numbers greater than 0 or the letter u

Comment: So, as I say, use `'u'`, not `u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have been like this

```
AND (a.d_max > '0' OR a.d_max = 'u') AND (a.max > '0' OR a.max = 'u')
```

Comment: Or rather this: `AND (a.d_max > 0 OR a.d_max = 'u') AND (a.max > 0 OR a.max = 'u')` ...